# Hosting full stack web application on Heroku

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, web-applications, heroku

I have a full stack web application that I want to host on Heroku. I have never deployed a web application so I don't know where to begin. Can anyone help me out? The frontend is HTML/CSS/JS(angular) and the backend is java(spring) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction) pretty much goes through everything that you need to do to deploy to heroku.

Basically, if you have your code hosted on github already, you can just create the app on heroku, add a heroku remote (git add remote 'git@heroku.com:yourapp.git') and push to heroku (git push heroku master). If you are unfamiliar with [git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started), I suggest you start with that.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, Heroku has a developer manual here [Heroku Java Development](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java) Going through that, you will realise that Heroku gives you tomcat/jetty support only, but you must use embedded versions, and fireup everything on your own.

I guess since you have to fireup everything on your own, using even a full-fledged javaee could be possible, the only problem is firing it up, and tomcat/jetty gives you an easier option.

Comment: Okay so if I deploy the backend, how should the frontend tie in? Should the front end be a view in my Spring backend, or completely seperate (hosted elsewhere)? Hosting it elsewhere is what I planned on doing before.

Comment: I figure that will depend a lot on how you are modeling your backend and frontend. If using spring, the spring manual would help (i am not so much into spring stuff)